# KeyError: '[706] not found in axis'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame which I want to drop the outliers and store them in **total_outliers** like this:

```
Area_outliers = np.where(df['Area'] > upper_Area)
Price_outliers = np.where(df['Price'] > upper_Price)
# Return the unique, sorted array of values that are in either of the two input arrays.
total_outliers = np.union1d(Area_outliers, Price_outliers)
```

Here is my outliers :

```
total_outliers

array([  25,   58,   83,  101,  145,  159,  160,  166,  173,  176,  187,
        189,  193,  195,  196,  200,  210,  215,  218,  220,  226,  234,
        235,  238,  260,  262,  264,  269,  270,  281,  283,  284,  297,
        299,  315,  327,  329,  338,  339,  340,  342,  343,  344,  345,
        346,  347,  348,  349,  351,  353,  355,  356,  362,  363,  364,
        394,  410,  411,  412,  429,  430,  436,  439,  458,  463,  496,
        512,  514,  515,  516,  525,  534,  547,  553,  559,  564,  565,
        566,  567,  569,  572,  576,  577,  578,  579,  582,  599,  600,
        610,  627,  635,  638,  640,  641,  648,  649,  652,  706,  712,
        721,  729,  730,  731,  738,  739,  740,  753,  765,  792,  803,
        804,  816,  819,  828,  834,  836,  849,  872,  876,  891,  955,
        956,  962, 1005, 1006, 1012, 1021, 1022, 1028, 1031, 1033, 1103,
       1110, 1114, 1128, 1136, 1137, 1148, 1174, 1175, 1228, 1230, 1231,
       1232, 1258, 1260, 1265, 1266, 1270, 1282, 1287, 1305, 1306, 1307,
       1308, 1309, 1318, 1323, 1327, 1328, 1337, 1340, 1344, 1345, 1347,
       1350, 1352, 1354, 1361, 1384, 1396, 1397, 1401, 1402, 1403, 1410,
       1420, 1421, 1422, 1423, 1424, 1428, 1430, 1432, 1433, 1438, 1439,
       1458, 1478, 1480, 1483, 1521, 1526, 1529, 1540, 1541, 1546, 1559,
       1560, 1562, 1581, 1582, 1585, 1598, 1607, 1619, 1629, 1636, 1638,
       1643, 1644, 1646, 1652, 1659, 1676, 1687, 1688, 1694, 1701, 1705,
       1715, 1717, 1720, 1734, 1761, 1762, 1772, 1785, 1800, 1803, 1804,
       1814, 1820, 1821, 1847, 1851, 1855, 1856, 1861, 1864, 1876, 1878,
       1905, 1909, 1911, 1912, 1913, 1924, 1935, 1963, 1966, 1967, 1977,
       1978, 1979, 1980, 1982, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1995, 1996,
       1997, 1999, 2000, 2004, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2013, 2022, 2023, 2025,
       2084, 2102, 2133, 2160, 2161, 2168, 2169, 2184, 2226, 2255, 2263,
       2264, 2267, 2271, 2303, 2309, 2320, 2323, 2339, 2346, 2349, 2350,
       2353, 2356, 2358, 2359, 2360, 2363, 2382, 2383, 2389, 2455, 2463,
       2465, 2468, 2489, 2506, 2519, 2548, 2564, 2567, 2571, 2585, 2615,
       2627, 2634, 2676, 2680, 2693, 2709, 2765, 2788, 2796, 2836, 2877,
       2931, 2946, 2955, 2977, 2986, 3002, 3036, 3041, 3049, 3061, 3073,
       3092, 3096, 3100, 3117, 3125, 3167, 3168, 3177, 3197, 3221, 3227,
       3237, 3238, 3247, 3250, 3253, 3271, 3306, 3314, 3345, 3352, 3367,
       3373, 3415, 3419])
```

the point is that `total_outliers` stored in array and I have to drop the data which stored in this array

I have tried this :

```
df = df.copy()
df.drop(total_outliers, inplace = True)  
df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
print(f"Shape of new dataset: {df.shape}")
```

but get the following error :

```
'[706] not found in axis'
```

by the way I gave it the axis and encountered that error again.

what should I do?

Comment: Insert the following line after `df = df.copy()`: `print(df.get(706, 'please check which columns your DataFrame has.'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the operations: select `area_good` based on `df['Area'] > upper_Area`, similarly take `price_good`, then take an intersection instead of union, and create a new dataframe from those indices.